# Slurm - Accessing stdout/stderr location of a completed job

Tags: slurm

I am trying to get the location of the stdout and stderr file of an already completed job.

Indeed, while the job is running, I could do

`scontrol show job $JobId`

However, this does not work after a job is finished

I am able to get information about previous completed jobs with `sacct`,
However, there is no option to display the location of stderr and stdout with this command.

The only information, I found about this issue is this https://groups.google.com/g/slurm-users/c/e4cZMbtrMM0 . However, this suggests changing `slurm.conf` so that `scontrol show job $JobId` retains information. This is not possible in my case because I do not have access to `slurm.conf`

So I was wondering if there was a way with slurm to get the location of the stdout and stderr of a completed job?

Thanks for your help

---- edit ----

The jobs are submitted with a bash file

```
#SBATCH --output=...
#SBATCH --error=...
```

By running the command `sbatch $submission_file`

This means retrieving the command to submitted the file does not help. Indeed this will retrieve only `sbatch $jobfile` and not give any further information on the output and error directory.

Answer (score 2):

Although Slurm does not seem to save that information in the accounting database explicitly, it does save the information of the working directory, which you can obtain with

```
sacct -j <JOBID> -o workdir%-100
```

Most of the time, chances are the output and error files will be relative to that directory.

Slurm also saves the submission command, which you can retrieve with

```
sacct -j <JOBID> -o SubmitLine%-100
```

which will reveal output and error files in the case they were provided in the command line.

Finally, note that Slurm will also save the full submission script [if configured to do so](https://slurm.schedmd.com/slurm.conf.html#OPT_job_script) (which could not be the case on your cluster). If so, you can retrieve it with

```
sacct -j <JOBID> --batch-script
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Unfortunately, I am using a bash file to submit my jobs. This means that the value of out and err are not directly specified in the command line. I added this explanation in an edit. This means that suggestions 1 and 2 did not work. I have tried suggestion 3 also but this returns None as I believe the cluster is not configured to save the submission script. So I was wondering if there is some other way to extract the error and output file location in slurm.